# Convert Godaddy certificate to .pfx file

Tags: openssl

I got an ssl certificate from GoDaddy and downloaded the certicate and two text files.  I need a pfx file for an Azure Web Service app.  Godaddy sent me two .crt files and two text files one of which is a text titled "generate-private-key.txt".
Question 1 : is the private key text file valid input as a key file for the OpenSSL pfx file conversion utility.
Question 2 : Is there any indication in the .crt file name on which file to use as input to the OpenSSL utility.

Answer (score 7):

First off, you normally generate a certificate request with your private key and then give the request to the CA (Go Daddy in this instance).  That way the CA does NOT get there hands on your private key.

If you just asked for a certificate without a certificate request then the CA will have to have generated a private key for you (not really a good idea as this is the key to using your certificate and now the CA has access to it...).  If you did this then the CA must supply you with the private key along with any password set on it (if any).

It is also recommended that you also get the intermediate certificates between your generated certificate to the CA root certificate.  These are useful as some clients will not be able to connect to your server without them being supplied e.g. firefox browser.

So you want to combine the private key, CA supplied public certificate and the CA intermediate certificates into a PFX file to be used by your web server.

The private keys can be in one to two main formats:

- DER - this is a binary format
- PEM - this is a text format - it's a base64 version of the DER format with headers and footers around it.

The certificate keys can come in a number of formats but the most likely are:
 - DER - this is a binary format
 - PEM - this is a text format - it's a base64 version of the DER format with headers and footers around it.

The file extensions are not always the best indicators of what the format is.  Try viewing them in a text editor to see if it looks like binary or base64 text with headers and footers around them.

The basic command in openssl to generate a PFX file is the [pkcs12](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/pkcs12.html) command.

You would normally do something like:

> openssl pkcs12 -export -out name.pfx xxx

Where "xxx" depends on the what you have to supply.  If for example you have:

- key.pem - private key in pem format
- cert.pem - public key in pem format
- inter.pem - CA intermediate certificate in pem format

then the whole command will be:

> openssl pkcs12 -export -out name.pfx -inkey key.pem -in cert.pem -certfile inter.pem

If you don't want to include the inter.pem just drop the "-certfile inter.pem" argument.

If any of your files are in the DER format you will need to convert them to PEM format first.

For certificates you use the openssl [x509](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/x509.html) command like this:

> openssl x509 -in cert.der -inform der -out cert.pem

Converting private keys will depend on the type of private key using the openssl [rsa](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/rsa.html) or [ec](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/ec.html) commands.  The command format is basically the same for converting keys are certificates but your use the rsa or ec instead of x509.

Comment: Clicking on the either of the .crt files opens the a Certificate window with three tabs.  The details tab has a Copy to File button with a which renders an export wizard with raio buttos for the vatous formats :

Comment: sorry - continued : the choices are : DER encoded binary x.509; Base-64 encoded X.509; Cryptographic Message Syntax Standard - PKCS #7 Certficates (.P7B) with an option to include all certificates in the certification path if possible.

Comment: continued again (that pesky Enter key) : Two other options are : Personal Information Exchange  -PKCS #12 (.PFX) and Microsoft Serialized Certificate Store (.SST). Both of these selections are grayed out.  The main issue is that I have a 25 line node.js app that renders a geolocation Google map published as an Azure Web App that works intermittently.  Google maps js API requires SSL to work properly.  Microsoft docs indicate to use a PFX file to install a cert on a custom domain in Azure App Services.  Not being a cert expert I need some clarity on this issue.

Comment: If you can bring up the certificate window, then the file is in DER format as windows doesn't really support PEM very well.  Base64 encoded x509 is PEM format.

Comment: The options are greyed out because it's a single certificate file and .pfx / .sst are "containers" of certificates.  There is no point in converting a single certificate to a container of one. If you did that in the Certificate manager application then those options may light up allowing you to export from the certificate store to a file.

Comment: Why does your command have three pem files? GoDaddy only has one pem file (and a crt file and a p7b file).

Comment: The command `openssl pkcs12 -export -out pfx.pfx pem.pem` does _not_ work.

Comment: Both PEM and PFX (PKCS) are conatiners of certfiicate information.  The difference is that PEM is a text format and PFX is a binary format.  I am assuming that the GoDaddy provided PEM contains multiple certificates (private key, certificate, maybe intermediate certificates).  You should be able to open the pem file in a text editor (like notepad).  If your PEM file contains both a public and privite key you can use the same pem file in the multiple parts of the openssl command. e.g. openssl pkcs12 -export -out out.pfx -inkey in.pem -in in.pem

Comment: I would assume the .crt file supplied will be a DER formatted certificate and the p7b will be a PKCS7 formatted (container) file and assume it would contain the same certificate information as in the PEM.

Comment: Where are these `openssl` commands typed in? This doesn't appear to be a valid command line command or program.

Comment: You will have to more specific that what command line doesn't work.  The command command "openssl pkcs12 -export -out pfx.pfx pem.pem" doesn't work because the last part is invalid (pem.pem).  An example that would work is: "openssl pkcs12 -export -out name.pfx -inkey key.pem -in cert.pem -certfile inter.pem" assuming key.pem, cert.pem and inter.pem are "correct" pem files. i.e. key.pem has priviate key, cert.pem has certificate and inter.pem has one or more intermediate certificates in them.

Comment: The openssl command has a very large number of command line options that make it very confusing to use if you don't understand what you are doing.  So there is normally no one "magic" command line you can use to get something done.  You need to taylor the comamnd line to your specific situation.  To create a PFX file you need:  private key, public key certificate and optionally one or more intermediate certificates.  These can be priovided in multiple different formats / containers which would change what openssl command line needs to be used.

Answer (score 3):

I found this to be very complicated.  Cobbling together these 13 steps was the equivalent of a Haynes manual 5 spanner job for me. Hope this helps and of course do provide feedback on whether any of these steps can be simplified.
For reference I host my apps on azure, and purchased a wildcard certificate from godaddy.

```
1. Create CSR (Certificate Signing Request):
    a. Open IIS (start, type IIS, should get Internet Information Services, if not you may need to install IIS first) on your development machine locally, 
    b. Service Certificates, Create Certificate Request. Fill out your company details, these appear to be simple free text fields although I suspect the company name and address should match with what you've submitted to godaddy.  Choose 2048 bit encryption.  
    c. Save CSR file on c: drive
2. Login to godaddy and rekey the certificate:  
    a. Login to godaddy, choose myproducts, certificates.   Click your certificate then manage
    b. Manage certificate section, paste in the text from your CSR file (open in notepad first locally) then 'add change'.   Then 'Submit all changes'.    It seemed to suggest then that I had to go all through domain verification now but this cleared when I refreshed after 5 minutes
3. Now in the 'Download Certificate' section, choose Server Type IIS then download zip file
4. Convert the crt file to a cer file:
    a. Extract the files from the zip file
    b. Double click the crt file, 
    c. Choose open, details tab, copy to file button then save the .cer file
5. Go back into IIS and choose 'Complete Certificate Request'.   Feed it the .cer file you downloaded.  
6. Chose a friendly name, I think this is only for your reference on your machine.   Then ok.  This should set your certificate up on your IIS locally.
7. Right click on the new certificate within IIS 'Server Certificates' section and choose export.  Add a secure password (you'll need it later). You can now export the hallowed .pfx file
8. Login to azure, go to your appservice that you wish to secure, and choose the 'TLS/SSL settings' blade.   Click the 'Private Key Certificates(.pfx) word at the top of the page (this is a tab).  
9. Choose the plus button to the left of 'Upload Certificate'.   Feed in your pfx file and your password from earlier.
10. Go back to bindings for your app. There is a small section marke 'Add TLS/SSL Binding' with a plus to the left of it, it looks like a heading but is in fact a button.   
11. Your custom domain should be selectable (if not add a custom domain in the Custom Domains blade), choose your certificate that you uploaded in step 9, and choose SNI SSL.    Add Binding button at the bottom.
12. Ensure the HTTPS Only slider is set to 'On'
13. Repeat for all your appservices.
```

Comment: This solution also worked for window servers... From point 1 - 7...

Comment: Perfect step by step!!!